# gitignore certain file extensions in the branch

Tags: git

I am trying to get gitignore to ignore all `*.gz` files under a `db/` folder, but not in other folders. Is there a way to do that with the .gitignore in the project root?

**.gitignore**

```
db/*.gz    # ignores db/a.gz, but not db/data/b.gz
db/*/*.gz  # ignores db/data/b.gz, but not db/data/extra/c.gz
db/**/*.gz # ditto, ignores db/data/b.gz, but not db/data/extra/c.gz
```

I have read man gitignore and looked through the similar questions here on stackoverflow, sorry if this came up earlier.

---

zsh v4.3.17 (x86_64), git v1.7.8.6, gentoo kernel v3.4.9

Comment: `db/**/*.gz` should ignore `db/data/extra/c.gz`. At least it does in my repos. What's your shell?

Comment: I double checked - it does not, i.e. `db/**/*.gz` behaves exactly the same as `db/*/*.gz`. I added the shell and version in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always include gitignore file in certain directories with single line

```
*.gz
```

I'm using similar method in mine repositories.

Comment: Putting a `.gitignore` with line `*.gz` in the top of the `db/` directory is exactly what you need.